# defining the control value in a model.matrix

Tags: r, model.matrix

When building a model matrix, I notice that when dealing with variables that have more than 2 values, model matrix seems to randomly select which variables to use as columns:

In example 1:

```
diet <- factor(c('high','high','control','control','low','low'))
sex <- factor(c("f","f","m","f","m","m"))
model.matrix(~ diet + sex)
  (Intercept) diethigh dietlow sexm
1           1        1       0    0
2           1        1       0    0
3           1        0       0    1
4           1        0       0    0
5           1        0       1    1
6           1        0       1    1
```

diet = control, and sex = f are inferred. In the case of the diet, the control is left out, and so I'm happy with the matrix.

In example 2:

```
diet <- factor(c('high','high','med','med','low','low'))
sex <- factor(c("f","f","m","f","m","m"))
model.matrix(~ diet + sex)
  (Intercept) dietlow dietmed sexm
1           1       0       0    0
2           1       0       0    0
3           1       0       1    1
4           1       0       1    0
5           1       1       0    1
6           1       1       0    1
```

diet = high is the missing variable. Now I know that this might be pedantic, because I know that R does not care. but is there a way to specify which of the variables should be left out (in this case I want the diet = med to be the control and therefore left out)

Comment: I found something online here regarding releveling: http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/expressing_design_formula.html is this the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: yes, that would be my approach

Comment: See `contrasts`, `C`, etc. Note the `base` argument. See also the `contrasts.arg` optional argument to `model.matrix`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice is not random.  It leaves out what ever the first level of the factor is. In your examples, observe

```
# from example 1
levels(factor(c('high','high','control','control','low','low')))
# [1] "control" "high"    "low" 

# from example 2
levels(factor(c('high','high','med','med','low','low')))
# [1] "high" "low"  "med"
```

By default they are sorted alphabetically. So in the first case, "control" is used as the reference when in the second case "high" is used as a reference. This wouldn't have been a problem if you have the same levels is both factors. You can adjust that by either setting your factors to have the same levels explicilty when you create the factor, or you can use the `relevel()` command. For example

```
diet <- relevel(diet,"med")
model.matrix(~ diet + sex)
```

Also, remember they are not "left out"; the default contrast is reference level, so the reference level winds up in the intercept them. If you fit a model without an intercept, the are all there

```
model.matrix(~ diet -1)
#   dietmed diethigh dietlow
# 1       0        1       0
# 2       0        1       0
# 3       1        0       0
# 4       1        0       0
# 5       0        0       1
# 6       0        0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sex <- factor(c("f","f","m","f","m","m"))
diet <- factor(c('high','high','control','control','low','low'))
diet <- relevel(diet, "high")
model.matrix(~ diet + sex)

#     (Intercept) dietcontrol dietlow sexm
# 1           1           0       0    0
# 2           1           0       0    0
# 3           1           1       0    1
# 4           1           1       0    0
# 5           1           0       1    1
# 6           1           0       1    1
```